# Normalising CGRect between 0 and 1

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best way to normalise `CGRect` values so that they are between 0 and 1 (unit coordinate system)?

Comment: @CodaFi This is nothing to do with CGRectIntegral. This is about converting to a "unit" coordinate system for working with various CALayer methods.

Comment: To any reviewers or mods, both the close votes are totally invalid.

Comment: They are.  I didn't quite read the question.  I'm not sure about the others, though.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to regard the existing width as 1 and the existing height as 1, or do you mean that you want the entire rect, with its current proportions, to fit into a 1x1 coordinate "box"?

Comment: Hi, this might make a bit more sense, it is the instructions from the filter "cropRegion: A rectangular area to crop out of the image, normalized to coordinates from 0.0 - 1.0. The (0.0, 0.0) position is in the upper left of the image."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A very concise way of doing this would be:

```
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0 / parentRect.size.width, 1.0 / parentRect.size.height);
CGRect unitRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, t);
```

Answer (score 12):

This should do the trick. You just need to divide everything by the width/height of the parent view or layer.

```
CGFloat parentWidth = parentView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat parentHeight = parentView.bounds.size.height;

CGRect rectToConvert = ...;

rectToConvert.origin.x /= parentWidth;
rectToConvert.origin.y /= parentHeight;
rectToConvert.size.width /= parentWidth;
rectToConvert.size.height /= parentHeight;
```

We say these kinds of rects and points are in the "unit coordinate system". You can read more about it in the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW16).

Comment: Why are you dividing the origin coordinates by the size?

Comment: @SeamusCampbell Perhaps because it's needed?

Comment: Doing so will return a `CGFloat` between 0 to 1 - which is what the user asked for..

Comment: @SeamusCampbell I suggest you read up on "unit coordinates": https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW16

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
CGRect rectToConvert;
NSAffineTransform *n = [NSAffineTransform transform];
[n scaleXBy:rectToConvert.size.width 
        yBy:rectToConvert.size.height];
[n invert];

CGRect normalizedRect;
normalizedRect.origin = [n transformPoint:rectToConvert.origin];
normalizedRect.size   = [n transformSize: rectToConvert.size];

CGPoint anyPointINeedToConvert;
CGPoint convertedPoint = [n transformPoint:anyPointINeedToConvert];
```

I thinks this makes it a little clearer what's going on and lets you take care of translations in an obvious way, if you have to do them.