# GPUImageCropFilter: How to calculate cropRegion based on a cropRect?

Tags: ios, gpuimage, ios-camera

After capturing a fullscreen image, I need to crop the original image based on an crop overlay which essentially is just a CGRect.

This is how it looks like

[image]

I understand that crop filter's region values should be between 0 to 1. This is the piece of code that is supposed to do the cropping

```
- (UIImage *)crop:(UIImage *)source
{
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(26, 75, 710, 710);
    // This is where the magic should happen to convert the rect to an OpenGL units
    CGRect cropRegion = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:cropRegion];

    return [cropFilter imageByFilteringImage:source];
}
```

Comment: Has that got anything to do with normalising a CGRect? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041538/normalising-cgrect-between-0-and-1