# How to convert normal CGRectMake into unit coordinates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

I am developing an iOS app using Rubymotion.
I am using the excellent pod/library called GPUImage and I need to crop out a square
image with the dimensions of 320 x 320 (squared). I know I can use it like this:

```
source = GPUImagePicture.alloc.initWithImage(original)

filter = GPUImageCropFilter.alloc.init
filter.setCropRegion(CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1, 1))

source.addTarget(filter)
source.processImage

output = filter.imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput
```

The problem is that I do not know how to convert my ordinary frame coordinates into unit coordinate system that the setCropRegion need to use (0.0 - 1.0). I know there should be some sort of algoritm.

The frame coordinates I am trying to convert are:

```
CGRectMake(10, 10, 320, 320)
```

Comment: Did you check out this answer? He gave a very nice solution without literals. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041538/normalising-cgrect-between-0-and-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think of them as percentages.

It will be:

```
CGRectMake(10.0/imageWidth, 10.0/imageHeight, 320.0/imageWidth, 320.0/imageHeight);
```

Comment: Ah cool. But the final result is not squared and very zoomed in. Wonder why?

Comment: If I switch them around it becomes squared! crop_cords = CGRectMake(0.0/original.size.height, 0.0/original.size.width, 641.0/original.size.height, 641.0/original.size.width)